# Find $a$ and $b$ for $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ is finite

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

The problem I encounter is

> Find $a$ and $b$ such that the below function $f(x)$ has finite limit as $x \to 0$: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^{3}{(x)}}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}-\frac{a}{x^2}-\frac{b}{x}$$

My first move is to write them all in the form of a fraction, $$f(x) = \frac{x^3 - \sin^{3}{(x)}(1+ax+bx^2) }{x^3 \sin^{3}{(x)}}$$
If I use the approximation $\sin{(x)}\sim x$ as $x \to 0$, then the function becomes $$f(x) = \frac{x^3 - x^3(1+ax+bx^2 )}{x^6}$$ This reduces to $$\frac{x^3 -x^3 - ax^4 - bx^5}{x^6}= \frac{-ax^4-bx^5}{x^6}=\frac{-a}{x^3}-\frac{b}{x}$$ Here I consider $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-a}{x^3}-\frac{b}{x}  $$ Because we want the limit to be finite, hence it must not approaches $\pm\infty$ Possible fixes for $a$ and $b$ is quite clear: Quotient is sufficient because we can invert $x$ to the numerator. So I choose $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$

But when I tried using a quite stricter approximation of $\sin(x)$, that is $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)$$ Then the quotient is $$f(x) = \frac{x^3 - \left[x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)\right]^3(1+ax+bx^2) }{x^3\left[x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)\right]^3}$$ Here is where I automatically stopped. How does the little o-notation behaves? I do not know what is the property of it, will it be $o(x^3)^3 = o(x^9)$ or another way?

How do I proceed from here? And is my result of the above solution right?

Comment: Relacing $\sin  x$ by $x$ in your second setp is certainly not permitted.

Comment: Really? My lecturer did that, so I just go for it but it kind feels weird.

Comment: Doing it in the second step is same as doing  it the first step itself. Does it look right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient precision in your situation is to expand $\sin x$ only up to the order $4$ (contrarily to the two previous answers):
$$\sin x=x+0x^2-x^3/6+0x^4+o(x^4)=x\left(1-x^2/6+o(x^3)\right).$$
Now, your problem was the behaviour of $o(x^3)$ when cubing that expansion of $\sin x.$

The first time you face such a problem, expand completely before "throwing to the common dustbin $o(x^n)$" (here $n=3$) all the terms which are "smaller" (once you get accustomed, you won't need to write these intermediate steps):

$$\begin{align}\left(1-x^2/6+o(x^3)\right)^3
&=1+3\left(-x^2/6+o(x^3)\right)+3\left(-x^2/6+o(x^3)\right)^2+\left(-x^2/6+o(x^3)\right)^3\\
&=1-x^2/2+o(x^3)+3x^4\left(-1/6+o(x)\right)^2+x^6\left(-1/6+o(x)\right)^3
\\&=1-x^2/2+o(x^3).
\end{align}$$

Likewise,
$$\begin{align}\left(1+ax+bx^2\right)\left(1-x^2/2+o(x^3)\right)&=1+ax+bx^2-\left(1+ax+o(x)\right)x^2/2+o(x^3)\\
&=1+ax+(b-1/2)x^2-ax^3/2+o(x^3).
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\frac{x^3-\left(1+ax+bx^2\right)\sin^3x}{x^3\sin^3x}&=-\frac{ax+(b-1/2)x^2-ax^3/2+o(x^3)}{\sin^3x}\\
&\sim\frac{-ax+(-b+1/2)x^2+ax^3/2+o(x^3)}{x^3}
\end{align}$$

and the limit as $x\to0$ is finite iff $a=0$ and $b=1/2.$

Answer (score 2):

The limit of $f(x)$ when $x\to0$ should be written as
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\frac{x^3-\sin^3x(1+ax+bx^2)}{x^3\sin^3x}\sim\frac{x^3-(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+o(x^5))^3(1+ax+bx^2)}{x^6}$$
Expand $(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+o(x^5))^3$, it will be
$$x^3-\frac{x^5}{2}+\frac{x^7}{12}+\cdots$$
So the upper part becomes
$$x^3-\left(x^3+ax^4+(b-\frac{1}{2})x^5-\frac{a}{2}x^6+o(x^6)\right)=-ax^4+(\frac{1}{2}-b)x^5+\frac{a}{2}x^6+o(x^6)$$
To make the limit of $f(x)$ finite, the condition should be $a=0$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I omitted the expansion of $\sin^3x$ where the terms order is greater than $5$, because $o(x^7)$ gives nothing.

Comment: That's quite a clear solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Expand $\frac{1}{\sin^3x}$;
$$\frac{1}{\sin^3x}=\frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{1}{2 x} + \frac{17 x}{120} + O(x^3)$$

Now,$$f(x){=\frac{1}{\sin^{3}{(x)}}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}-\frac{a}{x^2}-\frac{b}{x}\\= \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{1}{2 x} + \frac{17 x}{120} + O(x^3)-\frac{1}{x^{3}}-\frac{a}{x^2}-\frac{b}{x}\\=\frac{1-2b}{2 x}-\frac{a}{x^2}+ \frac{17 x}{120} + O(x^3)}$$

To make the $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ finite or to make $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$, the condition should be,
$1-2b=0$ and $a=0$; Therefore, solution: $b=\frac{1}2;\,a=0$